# Extension function asking for return type instead of parameter

Tags: swift, uifont, swift-extensions

I am creating an extension of UIFont in Swift that will return a custom font.

```
import UIKit

extension UIFont {
  func museoSansRounded900(size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
    return UIFont(name: "MuseoSansRounded900", size: size)!
  }
}
```

However, when I use the extension `self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.museoSansRounded900(15.0)` Xcode returns an error in design time saying `'(CGFloat) -> UIFont' is not convertible to 'UIFont'`

Am I doing something wrong? Xcode is actually asking for UIFont as a paramater instead of a CGFloat when I am using the function from the extension.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`museoSansRounded900` should be a class method as you're trying to call it directly on the `UIFont` class (which makes it basically a constructor).

```
class func museoSansRounded900(size: CGFloat) -> UIFont ...
```